# Why can't I show the excess characters entered in a textview?

Tags: android, textview

I want the textview to show excess characters entered and push the old ones left as in any standard calculator app where the latest character entered is visible. The maxLength = 14. When characters are typed (once 14 characters are entered as in the image) then it doesn't show them at all. I think I am doing something wrong but can't figure it out what. I have read other answers on stackoverflow for some similar errors and tried the solutions but it didn't work.

Thanks :)

Here's the xml Code for the textview:
     `

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/full_expression"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:maxLength="14"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="34sp" />
```

[image: When I click any other button it doesn't show at all after there are 14 characters already]

Comment: I was finally able to get this solved simply by increasing the maxLenght to 100 or above. Any value over 15 could have worked actually I think. The rationale is to increase the maxLength to a value which is more than what the textview can display at a time else why will the ellipses be even required. It is so simple. (unless you know it)

Answer (score 1):

Use "android:gravity" property to align your text inside textview.

Comment: But the question is not about aligning text inside the textview. This answer seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: If you set alignment to Right then it will always show your text to extreme right.

Comment: I tried that as this is what is precisely suggested in the answer just before you. And it didn't work. Just one thing. When I set gravity to right should I remove the gravity: end and bottom?

Comment: yes remove that and one more property is also missing there "android:ellipsize="end" add that as well.

Comment: Nope still not working :( The buttons give feedback of being pressed but the textview doesn't show the latest character pressed.

Comment: Got it solved. Check the comment on the question if you want to see the solution. Thanks for your help :)